# Asymptotics of convolution of a series given the asymptotics of the series

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, asymptotics, fourier-series, tauberian-theory

so I have a series of real numbers $(q_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ ($q_i \in [0,1]$) depending on some $\alpha \in (0,1/2)$ and what I know is the following, there exists constants $c_1, c_2$ so that:

$q_i \sim c_1 i^{\alpha -1}$ for $i\rightarrow \infty$

and

$\sum_{i=0}^k q_i \sim c_2 k^{\alpha}$ for $k\rightarrow \infty$

holds.

I would be interested if there is something like a Tauberian Theorem that could give one something like

$\sum_{i\geq 0} q_i q_{i+j} \sim c_3j^{2 \alpha -1} $ for $j\rightarrow \infty$

for some constant $c_3$ or something like that? It would be even better to get asymptotic results for
$\sum_{i=0}^N q_i q_{i+j}$?  Maybe there's also something?

Would be really glad if someone has a hint or an idea!

All the best!

Answer (score 1):

If $q_k \sim C k^{-r}$ with $r\in (1/2,1),C\ne 0$ then $$\sum_{k\ge 1}q_k q_{k+j} =
O(\sum_{k=1}^{\log j} k^{-r} (k+j)^{-r})+
\sum_{k>\log j} C^2 k^{-r} (k+j)^{-r}(1+o(1))$$
$$= O( (\log j)^{1-r}j^{-r} )+(C^2+o(1))\sum_{k>\log j} k^{-r} (k+j)^{-r}$$
Then $\sum_{k>\log j} k^{-r} (k+j)^{-r}>\sum_{k>\log j}^{j} k^{-r} (2j)^{-r}\sim (2j)^{-r}\frac{ j^{1-r}}{1-r}$ so

$$\sum_{k\ge 1}q_k q_{k+j} = (C^2+o(1))\sum_{k>\log j}  k^{-r} (k+j)^{-r} \sim C^2\sum_{k>1} k^{-r} (k+j)^{-r}$$
I don't know how to find the asymptotic of the latter series, but it is close to $j^{1-2r}$.

Comment: Thank you very much after such a long time! I have given it more thought and the solutions seems to be to factor out $i^{2\alpha -1}\cdot \frac{1}{i}$ and see that $\frac{1}{i} \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{q_i}{i^{\alpha-1}}  \frac{q_{i+j}}{i^{\alpha-1}} $ converges as a riemann sum :-)